# How do I round to 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a number with a comma, for example: `254,5`. I need the `0` behind the `,5` so it stands like `254,50` instead..

I'm using this to get the number:

```
Math.floor(iAlt / 50) * 50;
```

How can i get the `0` behind the `,5`?

Comment: Not that your descreption of question makes much sense! IMHO

Comment: can you show sample i/p o/p??

Comment: If you have difficulties expressing your question, you can always post code. Real and complete code.

Comment: @Baz1nga I've edited to make it clearer - great name by the way, Mr Cooper ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try the [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method, which pads the decimal value to length `n` with 0's.

```
var result = (Math.floor(iAlt / 50) * 50).toFixed(2);
```

A `Number` will always remove trailing zeros, so `toFixed` returns a `String`.

It's important to note that `toFixed` **must** be called on a number. Call [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert a string to a number first, if required (not in this situation, but for future reference).

Comment: Your solution does not seem to work. Instead, a simple .toFixed(2) does the trick nicely, it rounds up to two decimals (eg. 42.568 becomes 42.57 and 42.331 becomes 42.33).

Comment: `var result = (Math.floor(iAlt * 50) / 50).toFixed(2);`

Comment: @VasileiosLourdas The Question was a bit vague, but the asker wanted a solution that will turn 4.7 to 4.70