# I need to have 2 symbols after dot

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)
>   [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)
>   [How do I round to 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225558/how-do-i-round-to-2-decimal-places)

In PHP I can do the following to round to 2 decimal places;

```
$number = 3.45667;
$result = number_format($number, 2, '.', ''); // 3.46
```

How can I do the same in JavaScript?

Comment: You accepted an ugly and invalid solution. Good job!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var number = 3.45667;
number = Math.round(100 * number) / 100;
```

This will however not quite work like PHP's `number_format()`. I.e. it will *not* convert 2.4 to 2.40. In order for that to work, you'll need a little more:

```
number = number.toString();
if (!number.match(/\./))
    number += '.';
while (!number.match(/\.\d\d$/))
    number += '0';
```

Comment: no need to convert 2.4 to 2.40. I only need not to exceed 2 symbols after dot. will it work?

Comment: Yes, @pzztzz. Just fire it up in the Firebug console or on JSfiddle.

Comment: Your first solution is incorrect. Consider how it works for 0.005

Answer (score 7):

```
var number = 3.45667;
number.toFixed(2)
// returns "3.46"
```

`toFixed()` is the number of digits to appear after the decimal point. It will also pad on 0's to fit the input size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code

```
var number = 3.45667;
number.toFixed(2);
```

If you want to use rounding you'd multiply by 100 first, then round and divide by 100.

Comment: @Matt, rounding is exactly what was asked for.

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev: I imagine Matt was referring to the last sentence in the answer, which would be unnecessary because `toFixed()` does round.

Comment: Well, If he wanted floor or ceil he'd need to use the Math object

Answer (score 0):

the simple version: use [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) like this:

```
var num= 3.45667;
num.toFixed(2); // 3.46
```

the complicated version, if you want the exact behaviour of number_format() is using [this method from php.js](http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481):

```
var num= 3.45667;
number_format($number, 2, '.', ''); // 3.46
```