# how to show the var value to two digits after decimal in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have two var in html i want that when i divide first var with second then it show data like 19.30 instead of 19.3

```
var a =20;
var b=386;
var c=b/a
```

so c should show 19.30 instead of 19.3 in html java script.

Comment: why downvote if any body does not gets problem solved then he can post to get the information about the problem

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433122/how-to-add-a-trailing-zero-to-a-price-with-jquery/2433183#2433183

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225558/how-do-i-round-to-2-decimal-places/8225574#8225574

Comment: @AliSajad you get downvoted because it seems like there was no effort to solve it by yourself nor to use the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var c_formatted = c.toFixed(2);
console.log(c_formatted); // 19.30
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar suggested, i would also suggest the same. but make sure that the `toFixed()` will return a `string` not a `number`, so that we have to cast it manually either by inserting `+ operator` in the beginning or by using `Number()` function.

```
var a =20;
var b=386;
var c= +(b/a).toFixed(2);
```