# Division of a float/integer by a integer in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, decimal, division, integer-division

I am dividing a number( may be in amount format of XX.XX) by a  integer.

But when i do 6.6 / 6 or 3.3/3 , it gives 1.099999... , instead of 1.1.

What i am doing  is, I am dividing the amount equally among the number of people and if any remainder amount exists, I am adding that extra amount to one person among them.

May be something of this kind, 104/6 will be divided as 17.85, 17.83, 17.83, 17.83, 17.83, 17.83 [ May not be accurate, just for illustration].

JS Bin link ---->  http://jsbin.com/amileg/1/edit

Kindly help me in getting the right calculation logic.

Thanks!!

Comment: This is natural with IEEE floating-point.  This question has been asked many times; I'll try to find a good one to refer you to.

Comment: The "solution" is to pick a suitable number of [decimal places to round to](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8225558/901048), and do so (once, at the end of *all* your floating-point arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

That is floating point arithmetic and those are rounding errors . You can read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more.

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits, most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the characteristic feature of floating-point computation.

All numbers in JavaScript are represented in binary as [IEEE-754 Doubles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-754), which provides an accuracy to about 14 or 15 significant digits. They do not always exactly represent real numbers, including fractions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toFixed()`

```
var res = (vall / tot).toFixed(2);
//input `6.6/6`: , output : `1.10`
```

Demo `---->` http://jsbin.com/amileg/4/edit

Comment: Yes, but i dont want to round off. Please see the calculation i have said i am doing.